# SQLAlchemy one-to-many relationships with many possible different models

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Basically what I'm trying to do is implement a system where posts on a website can be reacted to with emojis.  Comments to these posts can also be reacted to.  To keep things clean, I'd like to make a single table for all reactions to posts and comments, since they're basically going to be the same thing.  So basically I'd have two one-to-many relationships, with the reaction table always being the "many" and two possible models/tables acting as the "one".  Here's essentially what I was thinking I would do, using Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```
class Reaction(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False) # The emoji code in format ":thumbsup:"
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id")) # The user reacting
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post.id"), nullable=True)
    comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("comment.id"), nullable=True)

class Post(db.Model):
    ....
    reactions = db.relationship("Reaction", lazy="dynamic", cascade="all, delete-orphan")

class Comment(db.Model):
    ....
    reactions = db.relationship("Reaction", lazy="dynamic", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

If I'm correct, this should work, right?  But is there a better, more standard way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Single Table Inheritance`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance) (Wikipedia) for this. SQLAlchemy supports this via the feature [`Mapping Class Inheritance Hierarchies`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance) (SQLAlchemy docs).

For single-table inheritance you create a field on your table to distinguish post and comment and create multiple model classes and pass a specific parameter to the `Mapper` (via the `__mapper_args__` attribute) for SQLAlchemy to use this "discriminator column" to know which type of object each row represents.

### Example:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # columns omitted
    post_type = db.Column(db.Integer)

    __table_name__ = 'post_or_comment'
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': post_type,
        'polymorphic_identity': 1,
    }

class Comment(Post):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 2,
    }
```