# One to many relationship to multiple tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, database-design, sqlalchemy

So I have multiple tables representing a website, and an `items` table specifying the properties of an item searched from one of the websites. An example:

```
amazon = Table(
    "amazon",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("search_time", DateTime, nullable=True),
    Column("search_term", String(255)),
)

bol = Table(
    "bol",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("search_time", DateTime, nullable=True),
    Column("search_term", String(255)),
)

coolblue = Table(
    "coolblue",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("search_time", DateTime, nullable=True),
    Column("search_term", String(255)),
)
```

And the items table:

```
items = Table(
    "items",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("title", String(255)),
    Column("price", String(255)),
    Column("link", String(255)),
)
```

I specify a mapping between the items and websites with their Python object counterparts (objects not shown in this question for brevity), and would like to have a one-to-many relationship between each website table and the items table. Thus I do the following (only for amazon is shown for brevity):

```
    items_mapper = mapper_registry.map_imperatively(item.Item, items)
    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(concrete_websites.Amazon,
                                     amazon,
                                     properties={
                                         "_search_result": relationship(
                                             items_mapper, collection_class=set, )
                                     }
                                     )
```

But then I would need a ForeignKey column in `items` table pointing to id of Amazon i.e. `Column("amazon_id", ForeignKey("amazon.id"))`. And thus if I want to support the other websites, I'd need a similar `ForeignKey` column for each. But then, this risks for a row, to have two foreign key columns being populated, which shouldn't be allowed (since an item can only come from one website). Also, the rows in the `items` table will then have `NULL` in the `ForeignKey` columns not applicable to that row, which is somewhat redundant for me.

Is it possible in `items` to somehow make only one column e.g. `Column("website_id", ForeignKey("website.id"))`, and like a website column name with an enumeration of all the possible websites? Or maybe some other solution that can eliminate the risk mentioned? This may not be an SQLAlchemy question but also a database design question in general.

Comment: Do you really need a table for each website?  Are there extra columns associated with the different sites?

Answer (score 0):

This question is kind of a duplicate of other questions but it is kind of hard to find what this is called so I'm putting this answer here.  Similar to this question:

[SQLAlchemy one-to-many relationships with many possible different models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894389/sqlalchemy-one-to-many-relationships-with-many-possible-different-models)

I usually just squish all those "website" tables together into a single table and have a `type` column to `discriminate`, as `SQLAlchemy` calls it, between rows.  I don't usually use a native ENUM because I have found those can be hard to `ALTER`.  I usually just use a string column and limit its values in the application with `SQLAlchemy` Enum wrapper (with `native_enum=False`).

That `type` column can be used to differentiate between the types of websites especially if there are additional columns included or not included between them but it depends on how complicated your tables are and how strict you want your schema to be.

This is for the ORM but describes different design patterns: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html#mapping-class-inheritance-hierarchies

Note that the concrete table version is not recommended because it causes a lot of complexity.  Having some single table that holds the shared primary key source of truth appears to be best even if you still want extra tables. (ie. websites + amazon_websites).  I don't do extra tables anymore and just shove it all into one like I said before (ie. websites(type=amazon|bol|...).  DBAs be like ewww but its so much easier unless you have a ton of different people and services using your db I don't see anything wrong with it.  It does cause unused columns to be `nullable=True` and filled with `NULL`s.